# Suma de secuencias numéricas

Tags: java

Actualmente estoy estudiando Java y tengo un ejercicio donde me solicitan crear la secuencia 1, 2 , 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128.... Luego, el usuario me debe solicitar un número y yo tengo que utilizar una suma de los números anteriores al mismo que se encuentren dentro la secuencia para lograr obtener el mismo resultado (Ejemplo #1: 20 = 16 + 4 // Ejemplo #2: 15 = 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 // Ejemplo # 3: 4 = 4. La secuencia la logré encontrar mediante el código siguiente, sin embargo, me gustaría entender el algoritmo de la sumatoria.

```
  int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor ingrese un número: ")
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i *= 2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

---

Comment: Pro tip: 2⁰ + 2¹ + 2² + ... + 2^n = 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: @Fedex7501, muy buen tip!!  Visto eso, el problema es encontrar la bendita n., pero me sirvió de guía para refrescar las matemáticas y darle una mano al op.

Comment: @Fedex7501 y DEVX75 muchas gracias por las guías!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Advertencia, no hay código JAVA, estos son algoritmos, tal cual solicita el op*

---

El numero digitado X, debe ser diferente de cero ( ya que no está incluido en la secuencia)
puede ser en términos de potencias de 2 una sumatoria de números de la secuancia, o un valor único

```
Ejemplos
16 -> 16
15 -> 8 4 2 1
14 -> 8 4 2
13 -> 8 4 1
```

Así que el ejercicio debe iniciar con una generación de números de la secuencia menores o iguales al valor X

```
Así pues, revisando la hipótesis:
34 = 32 2
33 = 32 1
27 = 16 8 2 1
```

El problema primario es determinar el valor del exponente n para iniciar la secuencia inversa de potencias de 2.

**Para encontrar n, se puede utilizar el logaritmo binario o base 2, que en java y muchos otros lenguajes no existe como función directa, pero se implementa de esta manera:
n = LogN(X) / LogN(2)**

LogN es el logaritmo de base 10, comunes o vulgares, que **en java se impelementan como math.log10( )**

Entonces si x = 49 y n es una variable de tipo ENTERO (para evitar decimales en el resultado)

```
n = LogN(49) / LogN(2)
```

dando como resultado n = 5

entonces la primera potencia de 2 de la secuencia sería,  2^5 = 32

una vez encontrado n, podemos utilizar un for para recorrer los valores de n = 5 hasta 0 y listar primeramente la secuencia

```
para i=n, mientras i >= 0, i = i  - 1 hacer
    imprimir 2^i 
fin para
```

**Luego el algoritmo de la sumatoria:**

La sumatoria de valores de la secuencia se resuelve por medio de otro bucle, un while que efectua operaciones sucesivas con el restante

```
//agregaremos el elemento inicial de la secuencia a la sumatoria
sumatoria = 2^n
resto = x - sumatoria // actualizaremos el resto
imprime (2^n) // imprimiremos el valor de la secuencia

//Iterar para el resto
Mientras (n > 0 y resto > 0)
    imprime ("+")
    n = LogN(resto)/LogN(2)
    sumatoria = sumatoria + 2^n
    resto = x - sumatoria
    imprime (2^n)
Fin Mientras
```

Answer (score 0):

Para entender este algoritmo primero hay que explicar que significa cada campo en el for.

`for ( [declaracion de variable] ; [valor a comprobar] ; [incremento o decremento de la variable]).`

Podemos tratar de desglozar el algoritmo para entenderlo mas facil

Usare un while para explicarlo mas detalladamente.

```java
int valorIngresado = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor ingrese un número: ");
int valorActual = 1;

while (valorIngresado > valorActual ) { // El ciclo se ejecutara mientras el valor ingresado sea menor que el valor actual.
System.out.println(valorActual) // Imprimimos el valor actual.
valorActual = valorActual * 2 //Lo multiplicamos por 2 para obtener la secuencia deseada.
}
```

En el momento que la variable `valorActual` sea mayor o igual que `valorIngresado` entonces el ciclo se detendra, y se entiende que se ha llegado al valor deseado.

> **Referencias**
>
> - https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Ciclos/Ciclo-for | *Ciclo For*
> - https://decodigo.com/java-el-ciclo-while | *Ciclo while*

Comment: El op, no busca entender el for, ya lo usó al generar la secuencia. Necesita ayuda con un algoritmo para resolver por sumatoria de potencias de 2, el valor digitado por el usuario de su programa.